# Link a file to a specific url of my owncloud server

Tags: network-share, url, owncloud

So I shared a file with my owncloud server, so It gives me a link in the format:

https://myowncloudserverexample.com/owncloud/index.php/s/SOMERANDOMSTRING

The problem is that url was printed to some posters, and I need to modify the file, and the owncloud interface doesn't allow me to modify the file maintaining the link, or create a new file and modify the link.

The question is: Can associate any file to that link on my server?

I have root access and total control of the server.

Thanks

Comment: You COULD create a redirect using .htaccess. So /owncloud/index.php/s/SOMERANDOMSTRING will redirect to https://myowncloudserverexample.com/owncloud/index.php/s/SOMEOTHERSTUFF

Comment: @Orphans Which .htaccess should I change? I have one in /var/www and others in /var/www/owncloud , /var/www/owncloud/data, /var/www/owncloud/config and neither seems to work

Comment: You should change the one in your DocumentRoot

RedirectMatch 301 ^/owncloud/index.php/s/SOMERANDOMSTRING /redirect-here/etqwgw

Comment: @Orphans It doesn't work, I searched for errors in the log but I can't find  anything relevant

Comment: Seems like your webserver is not looking for a .htaccess file. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file